# Android - Howto close current activity when Done-button in contextual menu is pressed

Tags: android

I want to achieve something similar to what the Contacts app does:

When pressing an edit-option in my main activity I want to show up another activity which allows some editing. As soon as this activity shows up, I also want to display a contextual menu (works by calling `startActionMode()`) showing the "Done"-button (left top) - like in the contacts app when you edit a contact. So far everything works fine.

My problem: pressing the Done button should also close the activity (like pressing the "Back-button does) and go back to the main activity, but I don't know how to finish the activity from within the `ActionMode.Callback's onActionItemClicked()` method.

I'm not sure if I'm trying to misuse the concept of contextual menu here, but it seems like the Contacts App does the same.

Thanks for any help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just override onDestroyActionMode:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
{
    finish();
}
```